# WPF Stackpanel Children unable to select using foreach

Tags: wpf

GUI create dynamically using the code below:

```
Grid gridBox = new Grid();
Grid gridBgm = new Grid();
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
stack.Children.Add(lbl);
stack.Children.Add(comboxBoxs);
stack.Children.Add(tgglBtn);
gridBox.Children.Add(borders);
gridBox.Children.Add(stack);

// add button into grid
Grid.SetColumn(gridBox, x);
Grid.SetRow(gridBox, y);
gridBgm.Children.Add(gridBox);
```

Output GUI:

[image: Output GUI]

foreach code below unable to check current toggle button when the current combo box is selected value.

```
ComboBox cbb = sender as ComboBox;
var gBoxChild = gridBox.Children.OfType<StackPanel>();

foreach (StackPanel c in gBoxChild)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel))
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in c.Children)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ToggleButton))
            {
                if (cbb.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    ((ToggleButton)c).IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Wan. Is this a question? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes , i cant get the third layer of the Grid control (means Grid - stack panel - toggle button) dynamically and i need to use foreach to loop to get all toggle button from the grid .thanks

Comment: Just don't use code for creating UI. Use XAML and data templating.